# CSS file being ignored?

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite

I have a contact page on my site set up like this;

**contact.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="webpage.css">
        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    </head>
...rest of content
```

I recently set up an htaccess page with some mod_rewrite changes.

So now, I have urls like

```
www.example.com/user
```

and

```
www.example.com/user/contact
```

When I look at `www.example.com/user/contact` the CSS is not recognized and the page does not print any of my divs but just some worded content.

So if I have

```
<div id="userinfo">
    User info
</div>
```

It just displays "User info" on the left of the page without the div being recognized.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Post the .htaccess mod_rewrite rules. That is what's important here. Most likely you are missing something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` in your CSS is a relative link. So for www.example.com/user the browser will request the css file at www.example.com/webpage.css, but for www.example.com/user/contact it will request www.example.com/**user**/webpage.css

That may cause part of your problem and can be fixed by preceding your hrefs with a /, so `href="/webpage.css"`. The / will cause the browser to always request from the root of your domain so it will always request www.example.com/webpage.css regardless of the page you're on.  If your css is inside some folder within your DocumentRoot (I assume you're using Apache here), you should be providing the full path to the file from the start of the doc root so possibly something like `href="/css/webpage.css"`

In the comments, Michael is also correct that you may have a rewrite rule error so please add that information to your question.

Comment: Actually it was this, GREAT explanation, wish I could give you more points!

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute URL beginning from `/`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webpage.css" />
```